# VBA - Adding Counter For Tracking

Tags: excel, vba

New to writing code in VBA, and I need to add in a way to count/track how often a macro is used.  I'm struggling to find any examples of a code that would perform this function.  Requesting any examples there might be for this.

Comment: Where will the macro be located (on many users individual computers or on a single server)? Where will you need to store/access the information (from within the macro? In a database? To satisfy your personal curiosity?)

Comment: It will end up being on a handful of individual computers on a singular server.  The purpose is really just to verify that the people using the document are using the Macros and not carrying over old, un-validated information.

Answer (score 1):

Excel VBA doesn't have any built-in storage that persists across sessions - when the application is closed, all variables are released.  However you do have a readily available source of storage - the workbook itself.  Here's one way to do it:

Make a worksheet called `Counter` (or something). Optionally, hide it so no one messes with it.  Then, when your macro runs, increment the value of `Cell(1,1)`, which will hold your counter value.

```
Dim runCount As Integer
Dim counterWS As Worksheet
Set counterWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Counter")

If counterWS.Cells(1,1) <> vbNullString And IsNumeric(counterWS.Cells(1,1)) Then
    runCount = counterWS.Cells(1,1) + 1
Else
    runCount = 1
End If

counterWS.Cells(1,1) = runCount
```

Comment: I placed this code in mine and attempted to step through it, but it failed at the line "Set counterWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Counter").  Do you have any advice on how to debug this?  I'm not sure if this makes a difference or not, but my code is in a Module...

Comment: @CalebEdwards -  You probably don't have a worksheet named "Counter"

Comment: @TFrazee and TimWilliams - thank you both.  I was able to add this into my code and achieved the desired result.  I did make some minor modifications with help from a co-worker: 

'Dim runCount1 As Integer
Dim counterWS As Worksheet
Set counterWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MoWCount")

'If counterWS.Cells(1, 1) <> vbNullString And IsNumeric(counterWS.Cells(1, 1)) Then
    runCount1 = runCount1 + 1
'Else
'    runCount1 = 1
'End If

counterWS.Cells(1, 1) = runCount1

Comment: Rather than just hiding the sheet, might as well very hide it.  A hidden sheet can be unhid(_is that even a word?_) through the menus, a very hidden sheet can only be unhid using VBA or through the VBEditor (can be found in the _Properties_ of the sheet).

Answer (score 0):

Use `static` when declaring your variable.

From ["EXCEL" Ytics](https://onestopanalytics.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/static-public-arrays-in-vba/):

## Can we declare a variable to retain its value from a previous run?

Static Declaration within a procedure limits the variable to that procedure – but helps retain values of variables from previous runs, until forcefully reinitialized by explicit declaration using ‘ReDim’ or value setting.

```
Sub MySub( )
    Static Cnt As Integer
    Dim Msg As String
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
    Msg = “You’ve run the procedure ” & Cnt & ” times”
    MsgBox Msg
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to attempt to break down my code in terms that don't make me sound completely new to technology...

I have a "MAIN" Module that runs two separate Macros; one clears out all data in the worksheet, the other clears out more specific data.  The "MAIN" module references to other Modules to perform this.  I created the code you recommended in my "MAIN", and it created the MsgBox, but only when I step through it in VBA, not when I select either ClickButton.  I attempted putting the code in the two other Modules but was unsuccessful there.  Any further advice?

Comment: This only counts during a single session - as soon as the VB project is reset (due to a code error for example) or (eg) the file is closed, the value is lost.

Answer (score 0):

This will build a table for you on a hidden sheet showing all historical uses of the macro up to the **n**th time the macro was used along with a time stamp so you know **when** the macro was used. With this, you can use equations to extract exact data that you want as well. If you want a cell to show usage count, just to "Countif("A:A","*")-1” ... (minus 1 to ignore the header in A1)

To Implement this macro:
Create a new sheet titled "MacroCount"
Set A1 = "Instance"
Set B1 = "Time Stamp"

I would personally make this the last thing the macro does so it will only count the instance *once the macro completes all of its assigned duties.*

Also, Remove the "Sub MacroCount()" & "End Sub" from the below code.

```
Sub MacroCount()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MacroCount")

Application.Screenupdating = False
WS.Visible = True
Dim LRow As Long
LRow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

WS.Range("A" & LRow).Value = LRow - 1
WS.Range("B" & LRow).Value = Now()
WS.Visible = False
Application.Screenupdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I attempted this one, but every time I run my macro, it is deleting the "MacroCount" sheet I created... Any advice going forward?  @urdearboy

Comment: It’s not deleting it. It’s hiding the sheet! This way nobody notices anything different

Comment: Right click on any sheet and select “unhide.” If you don’t like that part of the code delete both lines that see “WS.Visible” (one for true and one for false)

Comment: You know, looking back, I cant figure out for the life of me why I did that in the first place. Maybe I was mistakenly thinking it had to be visible to be edited at the time?